# Casting double to float all the 3 digits after decimal point is lost in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

```
        double temp = 136379828.125;
        float m = (float)temp;
```

I ran above code and m value is 136379824.0 
All the 3 digits '125' after decimal point is lost in double to float representation.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between single and double precision floating point numbers?

Comment: it's not `loss`. it's `float` representation of `double`

Comment: Why should this work? If it worked without loss, I could take a file, and make a double out of every 6 bytes (6 to avoid loss, the double is 8 bytes), then cast them all to floats, and store those. The new file is 2/3rd of the size and yet supposedly losslessly compressed. Now apply this again and again.. there's obviously an issue with the assumption that it should be lossless to cast a double to a float.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that it is because of the 32 bits available to represent the point and my value is on the boundary leading to the result.

Comment: @Zeeshan That's still loss...

Comment: Now that you understand that float cannot represent 136379828.125 exactly, you should review your decision to use float at all. Is it precise enough for the way you are using it?

Comment: Agreed @PatriciaShanahan We are moving to double and avoiding float as our values exceed the float limit

Answer (score 2):

The [closest 32 bit floating point value to 136379828.125](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=136379828.125) is `136379824`.

In other words, the `float` data type does not have sufficient precision to represent your value. Note that your value is exactly representable in 64 bit double precision.